# Somar números de uma coluna do MySQL utilizando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho vários resultados no banco de dados MySQL, quero pegar os resultados e somar todos os números de uma coluna, em PHP. Como faço?

Comment: Poderia detalhar um pouco mais sua pergunta? O que você já tem até agora?

Answer (score 8):

Primeiramente você precisa conectar com seu banco de dados através da extensão `MySQLi`, [documentação aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php).

Feito isso, basta rodar uma consulta utilizando a função [SUM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) do MySQL:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
$mysqli->query('SELECT SUM(coluna) FROM tabela');
```

E para utilizar o resultado da consulta:

```
$resultado = $mysqli->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Você não entendeu, quero somar os números dentro de uma coluna e não exibir a quantidade de cadastros,

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente, a função `SUM()` soma todos os números de determinada coluna da sua tabela. @LenoSousa

Comment: OK, mas como utilizar essa função? poderia demostrar algum exemplo? com base no código que já tenho.. 


$comment = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM catalogo_comment WHERE cm_item = '2'");

$comment->execute();

while ( $cm = $comment->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
            {
        };

Comment: O ideal é adicionar essa informação a sua pergunta. Mas basicamente ao invés do `SELECT *`, você substituir por `SELECT SUM(nome_da_coluna) FROM...`

Answer (score 0):

Pelo visto está utilizando `PDO`, então segue um exemplo:

```
$STH_SELECT = $dbh->query("SELECT sum(coluna_pra_somar) FROM catalogo_comment WHERE cm_item = '2'");
$totalSoma = $STH_SELECT->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro, 
"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object in /home/..."

Comment: @LenoSousa Me mostra qual query você executou